# how to trigger same name class only on current input text box in jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

hello i am creating ajax search plugin.I have created some dynamically div. suppose I have two input box field and the div which is dynamically generated have same name . So I want to project only that div in which user enter the value on  text box  not other, but it fetch result on both div whether I type on first or second input box.
HTML

```
<div class="row" style="padding:10px">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText1">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" value="" id="searchText2">
    </div>
</div>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#searchText1').typefast({
    hint:true,
    autocomplete:true,

  });
  $('#searchText2').typefast({
    hint:true,
    autocomplete:true,

  });
```

jquery plugin file

```
var timeOut = null;
var $current;
var $info;
var input;
var hint;
var comment;

(function( $ ) {

$.fn.typefast = function(a){
  $(this).one('keydown',function(){
  input=$(this);
    $('body').bodyAppend($(this));
    $(this).css({
        'position': 'relative',
        'top': '-34px',
        'background': 'transparent',
        'padding-left': '11px',
        'font-size': '16px'
    })
    $('<div>').attr({
        name: 'comment',
        class: 'comment'
      }).insertAfter($(this));
      comment=$(this);

  })
$(this).on('keydown',function (e) {
    var _this = $(this);

    clearTimeout(timeOut);
      timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        var m = _this.val();
        api.searchResult(m,e);
        // console.log(ui.input);
        console.log(m);
    },500);

  })
  $.fn.bodyAppend=function(m) {
    $(window).ready(function() {
      $('<input>').attr({
          type: 'text',
          name: 'input1',
          class: 'form-control',
          id:'result',
          placeholder: 'working'
        }).insertBefore(m);
        hint=$('#result')
        single=$('.single')

    })
  }
};

}( jQuery ));
```

My Question is that irrespective of number of input text field on page. My comment should point only the current input box in which I am on working. It should not update the other comment field
class single is the field in which ajax request result displayed.
What is the best way of doing this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this case you can set one common class to all input field and apply typefast function on focus event to that class.

For Example,
HTML code

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control searchtext" name="" value="" >
            </div>
<div class="col-md-6">
                <input type="text" class="form-control searchtext" name="" value="" >
            </div>
```

Javascript Code,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on("focus", ".searchtext", function () {
                    $($(this)).typefast({
                        hint: true,
                        autocomplete: true,
                    });
                });
            });
```